# Assign user to an enterprise app powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-service-principal

i have a question to the following topic. I want to add six Groups to every new created enterprise application in Azure. I have already an script which creates the app and anything else I need...
I only struggle to add the six groups. Maybe you can help me here?

Greetings Markus

`$GroupID = "****************" $app_name = "****************" $app_role_name = "Default Access"`

`# Get the group to assign $AADGROUP = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $GroupID $sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'" $appRole = $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $app_role_name }`

`# Assign the group to the app role New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $AADGROUP.ObjectId -PrincipalId $AADGROUP.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id`

That is the example but i do not understand what they mean with the role.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal?pivots=portal](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: You have security groups and each group can be assigned a role.  You are making an HTTP connection to a controller.  The credentials (including group) is passed from client to server.  The server can then automatically runs code depending on the role assigned.  See following and roles are addressed in the last paragraph next step : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/concept-learn-about-groups

Comment: @user23587070 do you want to assign Default Access to the groups?

Comment: @Rukmini Yes, I want the "Default Access" Role.

Comment: @user23587070 check my answer below to add groups to Enterprise application with "Default Access" role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** that: To assign **Default Access** as app role, you need to pass app role ID as **`([Guid]::Empty)`**

To **add groups to the Enterprise application with Default Access as app role**, make use of below PowerShell script:

```
$app_name = "testrukk"
$app_role_name = "Default Access"
$groupIDs = @(
   "GroupID1",
   "GroupID2",
   "GroupID3",
   "GroupID4",
   "GroupID5",
   "GroupID6"
)

$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"
$appRole =  ([Guid]::Empty)

foreach ($groupID in $groupIDs) {
   $AADGROUP = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $groupID
   if ($AADGROUP -ne $null) {
       New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $AADGROUP.ObjectId -PrincipalId $AADGROUP.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole
       Write-Host "Assigned group $($AADGROUP.DisplayName) to application role."
   } else {
       Write-Host "Group with ID $groupID does not exist."
   }
}
```

[image]

**The groups added successfully to the Enterprise application:**

[image]